# logstash not starting up in windows 10 pro - ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am new to ELK stack. I have installed ELK stack in Windows. The Elastic Search and kibana works great. But when i started logstash, it shows the following error.

When i started the logstash:

```
C:\Program Files\logstash-6.7.0\logstash-6.7.0\bin>logstash.bat
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\logstash-6.7.0\logstash-6.7.0\logstash-core\lib\jars\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\logstash-6/7/0\logstash-6/7/0\logstash-core\lib\jars\animal-sniffer-annotations-1/14/jar;C:\Program
```

When i tried to pass data via logstash:

```
C:\Program Files\logstash-6.7.0\logstash-6.7.0\bin>logstash -f logstash_apps.config
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\logstash-6.7.0\logstash-6.7.0\logstash-core\lib\jars\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\logstash-6/7/0\logstash-6/7/0\logstash-core\lib\jars\animal-sniffer-annotations-1/14/jar;C:\Program
```

I searched the missing file `animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar`  in the logstash directory. It was there in the bin folder. I tried searching stackoverflow and google but can't find a proper solution. Anyone give me some solutions to solve the problem.

`

Comment: Logstash requires Java 8 or Java 11. Use the official Oracle distribution or an open-source distribution such as OpenJDK, You can check your Java version, run the following command: `java -version`
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is being caused by the space in the directory name, as the log shows, it is not looking in `C:\Program Files`, but in `Files\`.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\logstash-6.7.0\logstash-6.7.0\logstash-core\lib\jars\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
```

Move your Logstash installation to a directory without spaces in the name.